# how to reload snippets without reload VS Code window by extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, reload, vscode-snippets

I have a snippet file server and a snippet extension. Extension will request snippet from server, when I change the snippet in server, how to make new snippets active without reload VS Code window.

Comment: That's not supported: [issues:118416](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/118416)